# std::ostream, truncate instead of rounding for floating-point numbers

Tags: c++, floating-point, std

I have my own io-manipulator that prepares a `std::ostream` stream to print floating-point numbers:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>

 inline std::ostream& my_fmt(std::ostream& os)
 { return os << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2); }

 int main()
 {
      std::cout << my_fmt << 3.146; // It prints 3.15
 }
```

I wonder how could I change my io-manipulator to force a truncation by the specified number of decimals instead of a rounding, which is the default behaviour of `std::num_put<CharT>::do_put`.

For example, in my snippet, I want the program prints 3.14 instead of 3.15.

I guess that the answer must be creating my own `locale` or a `facet` or something and reimplement the `put` function, by inheritance or by a partial specialization of `std::num_put`, but I'm not sure about how the IO-library and locale/facets works together and I don't know exactly what I have to do or what is what I need to specialize or reimplement.

Comment: Why do you suggest `std::fixed << std::setprecision(5);` applies a ceiling or truncation function rather than round?  What evidence?

Comment: @chux I've never said that. I want to "ceil the fifth decimal". By default, it rounds (nearest decimal) by precision.

Comment: @chux I've rewritten the question a bit to specify better the intended behaviour.

Comment: An alternative to changing `std::ostream` would be to simply supply a truncated value: `std::cout << my_fmt << trunc(3.146*100)/100.0;` or wrap that in some sort of new type `std::cout << my_fmt << t100(3.146)`.

Comment: @chux Yes but a manipulator changes the state of the stream for subsequents operations, which is what I actually need. Besides, I explicitely requested how to change the manipulator, because the 2 decimals was just an example. I actually have 8 decimals where, in some cases, the integral part of the floating point is huge, and multiplying by `1 / precission` could cause overflows.

Comment: When the `|value| > 1.0/DBL_EPSILON` there is no need to call `trunc(3.146*100)/100.0` and risk overflow.  Good luck in your quest.